# Blink shape depending on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a excel file where I will have shapes. 
That shapes i'm trying to connect to cell values.

So when I click on button start, excel will go through the cell values, of cell value is X, I want shape X to blink red, and if cell value is Y cell will be green.

For now i programmed code for going through cells in one column and changing its color to green and red:

```
Sub test()

Dim sh As Shape
Dim area As String
Set sh = Sheet1.Shapes("X")

Range("A1").Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
    area = ActiveCell.Value
    If area = "X" Then
        sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rgbRed
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop End Sub
```

I have a problem with programming the code to change the name of cell and to change the color of other shapes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait about 1 second between the selection of the cells in order to make it work. With your code and using Select Cell, something like this should work:

```
Sub test()

    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim area As String

    Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes("X")    
    Range("A1").Select

    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
        area = ActiveCell.Value

        If area = "X" Then
            sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rgbRed
            Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
        ElseIf area = "Y" Then
            sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rgbGreen
            Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Loop

End Sub
```

In general, using `Select` in VBA is considered a bad practice, but in this case it makes the "application" look better, because you can follow the current cell.